# Call an Activity's method from WebView using Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am calling a method from my `WebView`. The method executes a `Toast` whenever the button in the `WebView` is clicked. It works fine but when I pass an argument it doesn't work. The method is not getting executed when I pass an argument.

This is my `javascript` in `strings.xml` -

```
<string name="details">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;meta charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;&gt;
&lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width; user-scalable=0;&quot; /&gt;
&lt;title&gt;My HTML&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;h1&gt;MyHTML&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p id=&quot;mytext&quot;&gt;Hello!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot;Say hello&quot; onClick=&quot;showAndroidToast('Hello world!')&quot; /&gt;
&lt;script language=&quot;javascript&quot;&gt;
   function showAndroidToast(toast) {
       AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
   }
   function callFromActivity(msg){
 document.getElementById(&quot;mytext&quot;).innerHTML = msg;
   }
&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</string>
```

This is my `Activity's` code-

```
String str = "<html><body>"
            + getString(R.string.details)
            + "</body></html>";
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this),
            "AndroidFunction");

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

This is my `MyJavaScriptInterface` class:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        Log.d("tag", "cls");
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void showToast(String toast) {//without the argument this method executes
        Log.d("tag", "msg");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript syntax is incorrect:

```
function showAndroidToast(String toast) {
    AndroidFunction.showToast(String toast);
}
```

Needs to be:

```
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
}
```

**Additional Tips:**

1. You are duplicating HTML markup by wrapping your `getString()` with `<html><body>`. This is already included in your `strings.xml`:

   `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getString(R.string.details), "text/html", "utf-8", null);`
2. You shouldn't be storing all that HTML inside your `strings.xml`. Store it as a HTML file in your assets folder and call:

   `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/details.html");`
3. You shouldn't use intrusive Javascript like that, it'll be a nightmare to maintain later on. Have a read of [this article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript) to understand a better approach to vanilla Javascript development.

Comment: If I execute the code without arguments, the toast is displayed. What is the problem with argument passing??

Answer (score 1):

We don't use variable type in method calls.

Change

```
AndroidFunction.showToast(String toast);
```

to

```
AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
```